# Significance of sagging pants and visible asses in Kung Fu Hustle

Tags: analysis, kung-fu-hustle

Serious question, cause I'm really curious.

I love the movie Kung Fu Hustle, just re-watched a bunch of it on cable and the 2nd time watching it, how many other movies it references is just crazy apparent. The Matrix, Spider-Man, Road Runner (a bit too obviously), I even caught a Kung Fu Panda reference I think. Almost everything in the movie had a purpose and was deliberate.

**What was the purpose of the visible male asses in the film?** I guess that could be a reference to sagging "fashion", but that's usually visible underwear. Is there anything specific the director was referencing with that or did he just think it was a good visual? I googled, and while there's reference to this a lot, I couldn't find an explanation.

There's one in the 2nd final scene right at the end as they pull away from the lollypop shop, and there's a reference where his fat friend (now a good guy working in the shop) says "pull your pants up" to a bunch of kids.

Comment: Shorthand for young/immature/naive/clueless.

Comment: @cde OK, I don't know what that means.

Comment: *"Kung Fu Panda reference"* That was quite prescient, then. ;) (It came out 4 years later.)

Comment: @Walt   LOL, my bad on that one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Steven Chow, the creator of Kung Fu Hustle and Shao Lin Soccer, amongst others, was heavily influenced by old-school, physical/slapstick classic Hollywood comedy, some cartoons, some silent, some slapstick, like Buster Keaton, Charlie Chaplain, and Road Runner.  He likes silly, physical comedy.  The only significance is that butts sticking out = funny/silly (think SNL and the repair man butt-crack skit) on a very basic level.

If you want something more profound than that, then you are seriously over-thinking Kung Fu Hustle.

[Steven Chow article](http://www.independent.co.uk/arts-entertainment/films/features/stephen-chow-hong-kong-hustler-295387.html)

Comment: I wasn't looking for profound, only, the possibility of a direct reference to something, but since I couldn't find anything and since you imply the same, I'm leaning towards silliness/joke as the best explanation.  .

Comment: I wasn't really suggesting that you were looking for something deep, just that it was operating at a very simple level.  Thanks for choosing my answer over all the others you could have chosen!

Answer (score 2):

Like American Director Jody Hill, Chow displays his affection for "lower class" people by depicting them in funny but endearing ways, a recurrent element in his films. (Think *Shaolin Soccer*, *CJ17* and *From Beijing with Love*.) Since there doesn't appear to be a direct reference, this is certainly simple a gag.